# DIY Desk - Trestle stability

Tags: wood, safety, desk

I am trying to build my desk.
I can see a lot of positive comments about the Karlby worktops from IKEA and I think the 2.46m x 0.63m walnut worktop is exactly what I need.

My problem is that I already have two trestles from Habitat, which are 60cm x 60cm. https://www.habitatthailand.com/en/p/trestle-60x60-made-of-oak
So the trestle will fit exactly in the corner. 
Is this a good practice for the stability of the desk ?

- I am thinking about an extra leg in the middle (probably an Alex drawer).

Thank you for your suggestions

[image: Plan]

Comment: Show a plan of how or where you will put the trestles...

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @Solar Mike, just uploaded a plan

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Sure, you can hold up a desk with those frames. Success will depend on the details, though. How do you intend to fasten them to each other or the desk? How will you fit the center support? The bottom line is that general suggestions posts are usually too broad for our format. Please revise to ask something specific.

Answer (score 1):

Stable, yes. Your base is the same footprint as the table top, it won't tip over.

However, I would be concerned about the strength of the Karlby worktop. From Ikea's website:

> Table top/ Edge: Thick oak veneer, Oil-acrylic.
>   Backside: Foil.
>   Basematerial: Particleboard.

Particle board is not as strong as solid wood. It would probably hold a monitor and normal desk stuff, but I'd be worried about someone sitting on it. I would like to see support underneath. Typically you would combine a particleboard tabletop with an underframe, eg
[image]
[BEKANT Underframe](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/30255325/)